# Recursively Apply a Function with multiple arguments to a List in R

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply

I have a nested list and want to apply the same functions to multiple levels of this list. The functions are quite complex and require multiple arguments.

[Here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/02/rapply-function-explanation-and-examples/) i have found how rapply is used and though it would be useful to me. Unfortunately rapply only take functions of a single argument.

Here is an little example in R :

nested list:

```
x=list(1,list(2,3),4,list(5,list(6,7)))
```

functions with multiple arguments:

```
doAddition <- function(listIterator,
                       list,
                       add){
  
  item <- list[listIterator]]
  out <- item + add
  return(out)
  
}
```

I would use this function of the first level of my list such as:

```
result <- lapply(seq_along(x), FUN = doAddition,
                 list = x, 
                 add = factor)
```

How can i use the same functions for all my lists levels?
Is there an alternative to rapply that accepts multiple arguments?

Comment: `rapply` *does* accept multiple arguments. Your function also seems more complicated than necessary. Why iterate over the indices rather than over the list? That is, why are you not simply doing ``lapply(x, `+`, factor)``? This does the same as your code and doesn’t even require a separate function. And it also works with `rapply`: ``rapply(x, `+`, how = 'list', ... = factor)``.

Comment: according to the documentation rapply doesnt accept multiple arguments: https://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/base/html/rapply.html. Or am i missing something? How is it possible to pass multiple arguments in rapply? The function in this example is a simplification of a more complex function

Comment: The documentation you link says “`...`  additional arguments passed to the call to `f`.”

Answer (score 2):

You generally wouldn’t iterate over indices, you’d iterate over *elements*. Once you do that, your code is directly translatable to `rapply`:

```
rapply(x, `+`, ... = factor)
```

This unlists the results. If you want to preserve the nested list structure, pass `how = 'list'` to `rapply`.

Note that this isn’t using your custom `doAddition` function since, once you iterate over elements, that function isn’t necessary. If your actual function is more complex the same applies: pass an *element*, not an index.